# How do I split a string into 2 parts based on a delimiter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table in a SQL Server database with the following columns:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3
```

`Field1` is a column of type string with '|' as a separator.

It has the following form:

```
Part1|Part2
```

I'd like to write a SQL query which returns the following columns:

```
Part1, Part2, Field2, Field3
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You should ***never ever*** store multiple values into a single column - this violates even the **first normal form** of database design and will cause you endless grief and trouble - just don't do it

Comment: is it really this simple ?

select replace('Part1|Part2','|',',') Field1, 'Field2' Field2, 'Field3' Field3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function that could be used to split string in DB:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');
```

it will return all the values by splitting with space.

Answer (score 3):

One option here is to make use of SQL Server's base string functions `SUBSTRING()` and `CHARINDEX()` to split apart the two parts of `Field1` on the pipe character.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Field1, 1, CHARINDEX('|', Field1)-1) AS Part1,
       SUBSTRING(Field1, CHARINDEX('|', Field1)+1, LEN(Field1)) AS Part2,
       Field2,
       Field3
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of this approach(besides being short), is that it will not fail, if the pipe is missing.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(Field1, 0, charindex('|',Field1)) Part1,
  STUFF(Field1,1,charindex('|',Field1),'') Part2,
  Field2,
  Field3
FROM (values('abc|def','val2','val3')) x(Field1, field2, Field3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saing I totally agree with Marc_s's comment - Never ever store multiple values in a single column.
For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutly yes!**

Now, assuming you can't change the database structure, here is one way to do it using `Left` and `Right` with `charIndex`

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
( 
    Col varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
('a|b'),
('ab|cd'),
('abc|def'),
('abcd|efgh'),
('abcde|fghi')
```

The Query:

```
SELECT  Col,
        LEFT(Col, CHARINDEX('|', Col)-1) As Part1,
        RIGHT(Col, LEN(Col) - CHARINDEX('|', Col)) As Part2
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Col             Part1   Part2
a|b             a       b
ab|cd           ab      cd
abc|def         abc     def
abcd|efgh       abcd    efgh
abcde|fghi      abcde   fghi
```